# how to get file creation date of previous month's files

Tags: batch-file

I want to get the date of creation of  files saved in a folder, these files were moved/created last month. So now i want to check that how many files are from previous month.

Thanks

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you are under Windows try use Powershell, it will save you a lot of time.

```
$path = "c:\foo"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -File -recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-30)  } 
Write-Host $files.Count
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.  Actually i am writing a  script that will get the file details(there time of creation) for the previous month.